# Eslint/prettier javascript files

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

I currently have an issue where eslint and prettier don't do anything on my .js files in VS code.

Here is the content of my .prettierrc:

```
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 80,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "proseWrap": "always",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "requireConfig": false,
    "useTabs": false,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
    "semi": true
}
```

eslintrc:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "allowImportExportEverywhere": false,
        "codeFrame": false,
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
    "env": { "browser": true, "jest": true },
    "rules": {
        "max-len": ["error", { "code": 100 }],
        "prefer-promise-reject-errors": ["off"],
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": ["off"],
        "react/prop-types": ["warn"],
        "no-return-assign": ["off"],
        "react/jsx-indent": ["error", 4],
        "indent": [4, 4]
    }
}
```

I tried setting in setting.json

```
"eslint.validate": [
        "javascript",
        "javascriptreact",
        "html",
        "typescriptreact"
 ]
```

And nothing seems to work for the javascript file, where everything is ok for jsx files for example.

If anyone has an idea on how to fix this issue, thank for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the eslintrc file

```
 "indent": ["error", 4],
```